# Cocoapod Workspace Integration

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Currently I'm working with 2 workspaces: First workspace contains `MyLibrary` pod, created by the `pod lib create MyLibrary` command. The second workspace I'm using is my project's workspace which includes the project I'm working on.

Is it possible to integrate `MyLibrary` workspace inside the second workspace? It will be very helpful as I could see all my code in a single workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found documentation on this:

> **Using the files from a local path.**
>
> If you wold like to use develop a Pod in tandem with its client project you can use the path option.
>
> `pod 'AFNetworking', :path => '~/Documents/AFNetworking'`
>
> Using this option CocoaPods will assume the given folder to be the root of the Pod and will link the files directly from there in the Pods project. This means that your edits will persist to CocoaPods installations.
>
> The referenced folder can be a checkout of your your favorite SCM or even a git submodule of the current repo.
>
> Note that the podspec of the Pod file is expected to be in the folder. (http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod:)

Another important note:

> This is awesome for small changes that are made exclusively on existing source files. Adding or removing source files is out of the question because you have no access to the project file. For bigger changes like that, you should open the local project file. (http://www.cocoanetics.com/2014/07/development-pods/)

Great example tutorial can be found here:

http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/developing-static-library-for-ios-with-cocoapods/

Enjoy!